# Can I use a .sqlproj file in my .vbproj environment?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, localdb, sqlproj

I just got VS2013 because I had to do a system restore... unfortunately during the system restore my project's DB files didn't make it over.  So, rather than build a LocalDB from my .vbproj environment I decided to manage it in a separate SQL project.  The issue I have now is that I can't seem to find a way to USE my .sqlproj as the LocalDB while I'm working on my .vbproj.  How do I use my .sqlproj database in my .vbproj file?

I should be able to connect to the localdb with these settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AHA!!!! I finally found the answer.  I needed to use the right instance of my (localdb).  SSDT (.sqlproj) creates an instance called `Projects` in the LocalDB instead of the default workspace `V11.0`.

So in the screenshot above I needed to change the "Server Name:" to `(localdb)\Projects` instead of the generic instance `(localdb)\\v11.0`. Then it all started to flow together like the magic that it is.